# R.java attributes not being found?

Tags: java, android, xml, dependencies, implementation

So on my program I am trying to implement a third party API for the camera. I am using com.wonderkiln:camerakit:0.12.0.

When I added to a test project it was working perfectly fine. I have even used the exact same dependencies as you can see in the screenshot, on a test project and it would compile fine.

If I try to include this package in my actual code I am getting these errors.

Can anyone help?[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I had to just change my SDK compile version from 24 to 27.